# Skype and Steam won't load - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: skype, steam

I'm a newbie with Linux but have just installed a 32 bit version of Ubuntu onto a old laptop. Whenever I try to run steam I get this message in the terminal:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Requested Force create but SharedObjectMutex already created
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for  appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20140828032355)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1409196235)
Installing breakpad exception handler for  appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20140828032355)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1409196235)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1409240101)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1409240101)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1409240101)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1409240101)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1409240101)
[0906/154017:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0906/154017:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
Generating new string page texture 12: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
Generating new string page texture 13: 256x256, total string texture memory is 311.30 KB
Generating new string page texture 14: 128x256, total string texture memory is 442.37 KB
Generating new string page texture 15: 384x256, total string texture memory is 835.58 KB
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
```

If I right click the steam icon I get the normal store library list but nothing loads, this also happens with Skype it appears to load but no login window appears.

Reading other responses to similar problems I've tried installing the lib32 files but this has had no effect.

Comment: Just a note, you'd only need the lib32 files if you're on amd64.

Comment: I've found an ['official issue'](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3435) which is also from somebody using a non-amd64 architecture.

Comment: what is the make/model of your laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link will help with the Steam issue:

[Steam Game Not Loading on Ubuntu 14.04](http://steamcommunity.com/app/287020/discussions/0/540740501050360030/?insideModal=1)

They mentioned modifying the launch files in a text editor.